# jQuery: what correct use of .on() in this situation?

Tags: jquery, events

Consider the following markup:

```
 <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
         button
    </div>
 </div>
```

I need to run a function on a `click` event on the `child` class and I've got the following two options:

```
 $(".parent").on("click", ".child", function(){....});
```

and

```
 $(document).on("click", ".child", function(){....});
```

Is there a dramatic difference on performance between using a direct `parent` as a target and the `document` itself? To me using `document` seems as a more robust option (if the parent class was changed for instance) - just need to make sure it won't cause problems if I start using this method everywhere.

P.S. The `child` is added dynamically inside the `parent` hence I'm using `.on()`

Comment: Do you really need to just `on`? Do you add elements dynamically?

Comment: Yes - the child is added dynamically inside the parent - will add this to the question now.

Comment: There is no really difference regarding performance between both even it is usually preferred to bind event to closest static container

Comment: would `$(this)` then be `$('.parent')` or `$('.child')`?

Comment: Okay. I'm interested though - could you pls explain why closest static container is preferred?

Comment: @A.Wolff Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `.parent` event would only check for changes if anything inside of it was changed, whereas `document` would check for changes (and `.child` elements) every time any HTML on the entire site was changed, hence making `.parent` the preferred method?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you are correct, my bad. Indeed should be: `$(document).on("click", ".parent .child", function(){....});`

Comment: @user1775598 It is usually preferred because if you remove '.parent' elements, bound handlers will be removed too, not if bound to document level.

Comment: @A.Wolff While your new solution is way more dynamic, the browser would still be checking for `.parent .child` tags whenever any HTML in the *entire* document was updated, wouldn't it? Or is it smart enough to cache the `.parent` elements?

Comment: @h2ooooooo it would keep checking for .parent .child as it is being delegated.

Comment: @h2ooooooo But here we are talking about a click event. Regarding performance, this would not make any difference, really.

Comment: @A.Wolff It indeed seems that it's quicker to use your last solution: http://jsperf.com/onjquerytest

Comment: @h2ooooooo in your jsPerf, you are binding event, not firing it. In fact, binding event using delegation is faster because you bind it only once, not each time for each element. Firing event would be faster using direct bound handler but difference will be count in nano seconds, nothing a user will never notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".parent").on("click", ".child", function(){....});
```

binds your click event to only those elements with class '.parent' that are present within the document and the event is bubbled from the target('.child') to the element where the handler is attached. This is much preferable than adding it to document as, adding it to document like

```
$(document).on("click", ".child", function(){....});
```

1. Bubbles the click event from the target in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the document element.
2. As @Woff mentioned, bound handlers wont get removed on removal of .parent elements.

Comment: Just to clarify, nothing is ever bound to `.child`, in both instances the event listener is attached to the initial target; either `.parent` or `document`. The click event is then trapped when it bubbles up through the DOM, and delegated to the correct `event.target` -- if the `event.target` matches the `.child` selector. For this reason adding to the `.parent` is a performance increase in terms of reaction time for most browsers, but it will be slight.

Comment: @pebbl. Thanks. That was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

"Performance" should not be an issue in your case.

There is an obvious difference between your two choices :

```
 <div class="parent">
     <div class="child" id="A">
         button
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="child" id="B">
     button
 </div>
```

If you bind your handler on `document`, clicking on `#B` will trigger the handler.
If you bind your handler on `.parent`, clicking on `#B` won't trigger the handler.

You have to decide if what you want is to listen to all nodes tagged with the `.child` class in the document, or only the ones which are nested under a `.parent` element.

---

Other points to take into account :

- IMHO it is best to narrow as much as possible the scope of your actions. From your question, `$('.parent')` seems to be the best target.
- However, if your `.parent` elements are also dynamically added / removed, do not use them as binding targets. Try to target some other node which you have created, but which will always remain in the DOM (for example : wrap your html in a `#myModule` div and bind your events to `$('#myModule')`).
- `.stopPropagation()` : the main difference in delegation vs. direct binding is that the handler is executed when the event has bubbled up to the target node.
  If you rely on `.stopPropagation()` or `return false` to prevent the execution of other handlers, this has an impact on when the event is actually stopped.
  Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LeGEC/tz9Qj/) to illustrate this.